# How to get the value of the table using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, winforms, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

i Need to get the content of the table. Below is my table

```
<tr class="oddRow" id="activeFiles25472825Row">
    <td>Author Photo</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div id="active_25472825_CALLOUT" class="fileTruncateCallout" style="position:absolute; display:none">JCS.jpg</div>
    </td>
    <td>01/28/2017</td>
    <td>30.7 KB</td>
    <td>Member</td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://google.com.download">download</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my code. But i don't know what's next. I tried getting the value i need but i can't make it work. it didn't give me output, or error

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument newdoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    newdoc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
                    GeckoElementCollection links = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");
                    foreach (var itm in links)
                    {
}
```

And the output 
is

Name: JCS.jpg
Link: https://google.com.download

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? the text inside tds?

Comment: @HungCao good day. i need to get the div value inside the td. and the href attribute value inside the td tag. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, I didn't test it but hopefully you understand the idea behind

```
foreach (var td in newDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td"))
            {
                var div = td.ChildNodes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals("div") && c.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("fileTruncateCallout"));
                if (div != null)
                {
                    var name = div.InnerText;
                }
                else
                {
                    var aNode = td.ChildNodes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals("a"));
                    if(aNode != null)
                    {
                        var href = aNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
                    }
                }
            }
```